# AOSP ERROR: Dex2oat failed to compile a boot image.It is likely that the boot classpath is inconsistent

Tags: android, ubuntu, android-source, dex, android-soong

I'm trying to build android 12. I was using Ubuntu 22.04.2 where it worked successfully.
Now I've installed a fresh Ubuntu 22.04.3 which is using a new kernel and I started getting this error:

> ERROR: Dex2oat failed to compile a boot image.It is likely that the boot classpath is inconsistent.Rebuild with ART_BOOT_IMAGE_EXTRA_ARGS="--runtime-arg -verbose:verifier" to see verification errors.

I've seen this similar issue
[Android dex2oat build:ERROR: Dex2oat failed to compile a boot image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60275623/android-dex2oat-builderror-dex2oat-failed-to-compile-a-boot-image) - Nothing worked for me from this thread

1. Tried running build with additional flags:
   `ALLOW_MISSING_DEPENDENCIES=true WITH_DEXPREOPT=false ART_BOOT_IMAGE_EXTRA_ARGS="--runtime-arg -verbose:verifier" m -j4`
2. Tried remove flags ("-msse4.2" and "-mpopcnt") in art/build/Android.bp
   (https://i.stack.imgur.com/39O63.png)

Answer (score 0):

So after some digging AOSP code I've came up with this workaround. Note that I don't think its a solution - just a workaround.
Basically it figures out that WITH_DEXPREOPT is overriden in build scripts.
In my AOSP version it was in build/core/board_config.mk

Workaround:

1. In `build/core/board_config.mk` set `WITH_DEXPREOPT` to false
   [build/core/board_config.mk](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LgLii.png)
2. Silence the error in `build/core/dex_preopt_config.mk` by removing `$(call pretty-error, DEXPREOPT must be enabled for user and userdebug builds)`
   [build/core/dex_preopt_config.mk](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q62nM.png)

Answer (score 0):

It seems, in Ubuntu 22.04 LTS with kernel version 6.x.x creating some problem or it is not compatible to the build system. My problem was fixed when I downgraded my build machine's kernel version (to: 5.15.0-84-generic). Take look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77203755/6037446